# cannot convert parameter from `const char *` to `char *`

Tags: c++, string

Given this code:

```
void group::build(int size, std::string *ips){
/*Build the LL after receiving the 
member list from bootstrap*/
head = new member("head");
member *temp1,*temp2;

temp1 = new member(ips[0].data());  // error here
    // ....
}

member::member(char *ip){
strcpy_s(this->ip_addr,sizeof(ip),ip);
this->next = NULL;
this->previous = NULL;
}
```

And a pointer to string defined as:

```
std::string *ips;
```

I want to initialize the array, `ips` with strings but when I try to get the char data from any array member I get the error:

> cannot convert parameter from `const char *` to `char *`

Why?

Comment: The use of `strcpy_s` is wrong. Firstly, the second parameter is the size of the destination buffer, but you aren't providing that. Secondly, `sizeof(ip)` is the size of a `char*` in bytes, nothing to do with the length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line

```
member::member(char *ip)
```

to

```
member::member(const char *ip)
```

and, i'm not sure about your usage of `strcpy_s`

Answer (score 4):

The function you are calling expects a pointer to a modifiable buffer, `char*`. You are passing a pointer to a non-modifiable buffer, `const char*`.

Since your `member` function does not modify its input you should change its declaration to receive `const char*`.

```
member::member(const char *ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `data()` returns a `const char*`, hence the error. You should change `member::member` to receive a `const char*`, as you're copying its value anyway.

Also, note that `sizeof(ip)` is equal to `sizeof(char*)`, which is just a size of a pointer. You should pass the size of the `this->ip_addr` buffer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because member::member is defined to take char * as a parameter, and string.data() is giving a const char * as a value (since it is returning a reference to its own internal memory). You could use const_cast or change member::member method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
member::member(char *ip)
```

to this

```
member::member(const char *ip)
```

That is, you've to change the parameter type of the constructor.

---

Alternatively, which is also a better solution, simply make the parameter `const std::string &`:

```
member::member(const std::string &)
```

This approach lets use better interfaces provided by `std::string` class. These interfaces are much more better than C-string interfaces such as `strcpy`, `strlen`, `strcat` etc.

Answer (score 1):

std::string data has this signature

```
const char* data() const;
```

You are trying to call the member c'tor with which expects char * so here is your error.

Change this : `member::member(char *ip)`

To this : `member::member(const char *ip)`