# C++ cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'

Tags: c++

I'm not a C++ developer at all, but was giving the task of upgrading some old code from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2010.  I'm getting an error from the following code.

```
MessageGroup::MessageGroup(const char *name, WordCollection *words) {
    _name.assign(_strupr(name));
    setWordCollection(words);
}
```

Error:

```
error C2664: '_strupr' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'
```

Comment: And?  The error message is kinda self explanatory.

Comment: `name` is of type `const char *`. `_strupr` is looking for an input of type `char *`.

Comment: Interesting thing about `_strupr` is it modifies the provided string, converting it to upper case. Trying to modify a constant string is not that good an idea. The compiler is simply trying to tell you to not do something stupid.

Comment: why not using MessageGroup::MessageGroup(char *name, Wordcollection *words)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot convert parameter from \`const char \*\` to \`char \*\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791330/cannot-convert-parameter-from-const-char-to-char)

Comment: We need to see the `assign` function backing `_name.assign` to suggest anything safe and optimal.

Comment: I understand the error is straight forward, but I'm not a C++ developer and I need to figure out how to get the uppercase form into _name.

Comment: _Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL assign(const _Elem *_Ptr)
  { // assign [_Ptr, <null>)
  _DEBUG_POINTER(_Ptr);
  return (assign(_Ptr, _Traits::length(_Ptr)));
  }

Comment: @Darren You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35046373/edit) your question to include important details (i.e., not dump it in a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is a constant c-style string. It promises the function's caller that the provided string will not be modified inside the `MessageGroup` constructor or by any functions called by `MessageGroup`.

`_strupr(name) is going to convert` name` to upper case, violating the no-modifications promise. This is a bad thing to do, possibly even impossible as the memory region holding name may not be writable, and generates an error. Perhaps in the past it only generated a warning and was ignored. Not up on my Visual C 6 and it's default settings, or the project settings should the defaults have been changed to silence warnings, so I'm not sure if anyone ever even saw the warning.

Solutions to the problem are:

## 1. Modify `MessageGroup` to remove the `const`

```
MessageGroup::MessageGroup(char *name, WordCollection *words)
```

This may break untold other pieces of code that use `MessageGroup` and count on name passing through unchanged. I only suggest it because it's an easy thing to try. If it blows everything up, put the `const` back and move on.

## 2. Copy `name` to a new memory buffer that is writable.

```
char * temp = new char[strlen(name)]; 
_name.assign(_strupr(temp));
delete temp;
```

But consider a smart pointer instead because it self-manages the memory should bad things happen.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> temp(new char[strlen(name)])
_name.assign(_strupr(temp.get));
```

The nastiness here is we do not know the lifespan of `name`. Who is responsible for `delete`ing `temp`'s memory when you're done with it? If `_name.assign` simply copies the pointer as opposed to making and keeping a copy of the data, `MessageGroup` cannot do the clean-up because then `_name` will contain an invalid pointer. If `_name` keeps a copy, you're safe, but you now have the performance hit of an extra copy.

Modifications to `_name.assign` and whatever class `_name` instantiates may be required.

## 3. Sizable rip-up

Rewrite the program with modern techniques and `std::string`. The error you've run across shows that someone wasn't being very careful with their memory use and there are likely other time bombs waiting to go off.

This is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A `const` type cannot be modified as part of the contract of accepting it as a `const`; this allows other code to call yours without needing to worry about the value being changed. However, since subsequent code *could* cause modifications, you cannot then pass the `const` parameter to a method which accepts a non-`const` version - in this case, `name.assign` would appear to do this, so `name.assign(_strupr(name));` is invalid.

Answer (score -3):

If you really have to do it, you can use const_cast<> operator. Here's example:

```
const int j = 3; // j is declared const
nt* pj = const_cast<int*>(&j); // now content of pj can be modified.
```

Here's the link:
    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: No, No, No.  Do not cast away `const` on a `const` variable.  It is undefined behavior.

Comment: De-constifying `const` variables is a very bad thing to do. It lies to the function callers who believe the variable will not be modified and `name` may point to a non-writable region of memory leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please not be religious on rules! as you see in my answer I say "if you really have to"! That means I know in general you should not do it, and in fact it is undefined if you apply it to something that is originally constant and therefore outside your dynamic memory address range. But in practicality there are cases when a poor API on a library that you can't change easily brings a situation that you know that the "cons"tant-ness is just a formality of the bad api. So if you are sure about the case and you can't find any other way that is "Practical" to do, then go ahead and use const_cast<>.

Comment: There is no context where this is appropriate. Dealing with const-incorrect APIs may indeed necessitate const_cast, but cannot involve modification of a const object.